# sorting each session uniquely in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, sorting, session, meteor, key-value

I have publishing setup along with sessions to send out messages to the right rooms.

I'm currently having issues as to how do I go about limiting returned messages so if a room has, say, 200 messages in it and another one is posted, the oldest one is deleted.

```
//how messages are created
    Meteor.methods({
      newMessage: function (message) {
          message.user = Meteor.userId();
          Messages.insert(message);
      }
    }); 

//how messages are published
    Meteor.publish('messages', function (channel) {
        return Messages.find({channel: channel});
    });

//how chatrooms are published
    Meteor.publish('channels', function () {
        return Channels.find();
    });
```

Problem is, normally I would do this by putting this in the publications `{sort:{limit:15}}`
However, that doesn't work in this case and results in ALL of the messages being limited.
   They need to be sorted by room, or, well, per session:key.

Is there a simple way of going about this? Or would I have to make a method on the serverside to run .forEach channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Meteor.publish('messages', function (channel) {
    return Messages.find({channel: channel}, {limit: 15});
});
```

I have no idea how I missed this but apparently I can just do it this way.

Huh.

(channel:channel corresponds to currently set session's name)

Answer (score 0):

There's no decent way of publishing the top 15 posts from each room in a single cursor. If the number of rooms is small it might make sense to publish an array of cursors instead, each cursor in the array corresponding to a single room.